# Using jquery slice to get parent elements only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, jquery-selectors

I have this code that I'm trying to figure. Basically what I need is to slice or copy only the parent elements which `Program 1`, `Program 2`, `Program 3` and `Program 4` inside the list and not including the child elements.

I can't seem to find an answer in my problem and I believe you cannot get specific elements using jQuery `slice`

```js
var menuContainer = $('<ul class="menu" />');

var nonDegMenu = $('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone(),
  nonDegList = $('li', nonDegMenu),
  nonDeg = $('#footer .programs-menu .non-degree'),
  items = menuContainer.appendTo(nonDeg),
  course = nonDegList.slice(0);

//Append Non Degree Courses
items.append(course);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/programs">Programs</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 1</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program C</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program D</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 2</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program E</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program F</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program G</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program H</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 3</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program I</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program J</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program K</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program L</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 4</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program M</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program N</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program O</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program P</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="footer" >
    <div class="programs-menu">
        <div  class="non-degree">
          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include what result you are expecting?  It looks like you just want `course = nonDegList.first()`

Comment: You want to remove the 4 `<ul>` but keep the `<li>`?

Comment: @freedomn-m  
I'm looking for a way on how I can output or get the first level of lists which is Program 1, Program 2, Program 3 and Program 4 but not including the child lists or child elements inside of it

Comment: Can you change the html?  Give the ones you want a specific class (all the same class) and use that as a selector.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is generated by drupal and I cannot set specific classes. So instead it would be better to get the first-level of lists

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to use `.slice` for here.  Are you trying to get the first item? all the items?  Doesn't seem to have a use or a need.  If you're after a single item, then you need to specify the second argument `.slice(0,1)`

Comment: @freedomn-m the purpose of `.slice` is for example I want items `Program 2`, `Program 3` and `Program 4`. Excluding `Program 1` from the lists

Comment: Ah, that's definitely not in the question:  `.slice(1)` to exclude first, `slice(0,1)` for just the first.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes to your code:

1. Change `nonDegList` to this: `nonDegList = $('li a', nonDegMenu)`
2. Now you can just append `course` to `items` like this: `items.append(course)`

See demo below:

```js
var menuContainer = $('<ul class="menu" />');

var nonDegMenu = $('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone(),
  nonDegList = $('li a', nonDegMenu),
  nonDeg = $('#footer .programs-menu .non-degree'),
  items = menuContainer.appendTo(nonDeg),
  course = nonDegList;

//Append Non Degree Courses
items.append(course);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/programs">Programs</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Programs A</li>
            <li>Sub Programs B</li>
            <li>Sub Programs C</li>
            <li>Sub Programs D</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Programs E</li>
            <li>Sub Programs F</li>
            <li>Sub Programs G</li>
            <li>Sub Programs H</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Programs I</li>
            <li>Sub Programs J</li>
            <li>Sub Programs K</li>
            <li>Sub Programs L</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 4</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Programs M</li>
            <li>Sub Programs N</li>
            <li>Sub Programs O</li>
            <li>Sub Programs P</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="programs-menu">
    <div class="non-degree">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the event the sub-menu or sub-lists have an anchor element, I believe they will also be included

Comment: @clestcruz change your selector to `$('#header a[href$="/programs"] + ul > li > a')`

Comment: `$('#header a[href$="/programs"] + ul > li > a '  ).next().clone()`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way on how I can output or get the first level of lists which is Program 1, Program 2, Program 3 and Program 4 but not including the child lists or child elements inside of it.

As it appears you're interested in the text "which is Program 1.." and don't need the items themselves, you can extract this "first level" of lists into an array using:

```
var list = $("#header>ul>li>ul>li>a").map(function() { 
                     return $(this).text(); 
                }).get()
```

(this appears to be the second-level to me as the first level would be `#header>ul>li>a` and give just Programs).

Normally it would be better to add classes or different `<h1> <h2>` levels which would make finding the items easier and less brittle, but (as per comments) this is not an option.

You can then use `.slice` as needed.   If you need the first, it would be:

```
list.slice(0,1);
```

this would be the same as:

```
list[0];
```

Note that `.slice(0)` will return all the items so has no effect.  Omitting the second argument extracts through the end of the sequence (`arr.length`).

---

If you need the links themselves (the whole node, not just its text) then there's no need for map:

```
var list = $("#header>ul>li>ul>li>a");
items.append(list);
```

---

> the purpose of .slice is for example I want items Program 2, Program 3 and Program 4. Excluding Program 1 from the list

You can use `.slice` against the jquery array, using the correct arguments.

To exclude the first (see code snippet for working example of this):

```
list.slice(1);
```

to get first 2 items:

```
list.slice(0,2)
```

More info on slice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```js
//var list = $("#header>ul>li>ul>li>a").map(function() { console.log($(this).text()); return $(this) }).get()
var list = $("#header>ul>li>ul>li>a")
$("#course").append(list.slice(1))
```

```css
#course a { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<hr/>
<div id='course'></div>
<hr/>
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/programs">Programs</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 1</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program C</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program D</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 2</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program E</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program F</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program G</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program H</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 3</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program I</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program J</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program K</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program L</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 4</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program M</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program N</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program O</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program P</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="footer" >
    <div class="programs-menu">
        <div  class="non-degree">
          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```